# Reducing a constant voltage source from 24 V to 12 V

Tags: power-supply, step-down, solenoid-valve

I currently have a constant voltage source powering a PLC which outputs 24 V DC. I need to drop the voltage from 24 V to 12 V. Is there a way to do this without buying a $100+ DC-DC converter? The reason for the voltage drop is to meet the requirements of a pneumatic solenoid. The solenoid requires 12 V. Can I just swap the 12 V solenoid with a 24 V solenoid?

Comment: What is the output specification of the PLC? Perhaps you can switch the solenoid directly (assuming you have a 12V supply available).  If not, you could switch a 24V relay and use that to control the solenoid.

Comment: What is the current requirement of the 12V solenoid?  If at or below 1A and you don't mind dissipating a little heat a low cost linear regulator similar to LM7812  or LM340-12 should work.

Comment: please ask only one subject at a time  ... ask about replacing the solenoid in a separate question

Comment: What's the current rating on the solenoid? PLC sounds industrial environment. If you can keep everything to use 24 V, that would be my first recommendation.

Comment: "Can I just swap the 12 V solenoid with a 24 V solenoid?" is a question only you can answer. The general answer is "yes", but we have no idea if your solenoid is actually a replaceable part in your system, and if a 12V replacement for your current 24V solenoid exists.

Comment: As others have said, 24V is industry standard and the rule of thumb is to avoid 12V like the plague. Depending on what the solenoid is for, swapping to 24V might also lower the current consumption by half - this is the case for current controlled hydraulic valves, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would swap out the 12V solenoid with a 24V solenoid. All work arounds that are going to be proposed in this thread will probably work in a controlled lab environment, but will give you massive headaches a few years down the line. Or, if you're really unlucky, as soon as you deploy your solution to your production environment.

The only work around I would personally accept would be if you switched a 24Vdc relay with your PLC, which in turn switches the 12Vdc solenoid. But, as I gather from context clues in your question, you do not have a 12Vdc power supply available. So this would not be a cheaper solution either.

Solenoids are not expensive enough to warrant this much risk and effort

Answer (score 3):

A voltage-dropping resistor may be used.

[image]

It goes without saying that the ideal solution would be to use a 24 V DC solenoid valve.

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer, the source is regulated so if I just add a resistor the current will be driven up to keep the voltage at 24V DC.

Comment: Please furnish the model number of your 24 V DC power supply. That would be of help in arriving at the required solution.